# React filtering a list

Tags: reactjs, filter, callback, react-dom

I can't figure out the logic for the callback function in the below codepen.

As it stands the list gets filtered as the user types in a value to the input field. I can't figure out how to then bring the list back, if the filter gets removed.

https://codepen.io/benszucs/pen/BPqMwL?editors=0010

```js
  class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Mango', 'Melon', 'Kiwi']
  }
  handleFilter = (newFilter) => {
    if (newFilter !== "") {
      this.setState(() => ({
        options: this.state.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(newFilter.toLowerCase()))
      }));
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Filter handleFilter={this.handleFilter} />
        {this.state.options.map((option) => <p>{option}</p>)}
      </div>
    );
  };
}

const Filter = (props) => (
  <div>
    <input name="filter" onChange={(e) => {
        props.handleFilter(e.target.value);
      }}/>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are overwriting the original value of the state, you won't able to reverse it. I would recommend to create a new state called `filter`, and update its value in the `onChangeHandler()`. And in the `render()` method you should filter the results before displaying them.

Example:

```js
// the state
this.state = {
    users: ['abc','pdsa', 'eccs', 'koi'],
    filter: '',
}

// the change handler
onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
        filter: e.target.value,
    });
}

// displaying the results
const list = this.state.users.filter(u => u.includes(this.state.filter)).map(u => (
    <li>{u}</li>
));
```

Comment: Good to hear :) Don't forget to mark my answer as a solution if everything works well ^^'

Comment: @BenSzucs would you mark it as the answer as to help other people, as well as @peetya?

Answer (score 1):

In your handle Filter you can set the state to its default value

```js
handleFilter = (newFilter) => {
    if (newFilter !== "") {
      this.setState(() => ({
        options: this.state.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(newFilter.toLowerCase()))
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(() => ({
        options: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Mango', 'Melon', 'Kiwi']
      }));
    }
```

https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/pZxMRJ